# Variable containing alias not being expanded correctly

Tags: linux, bash, alias, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to automate `minikube start` process inside WSL2 Debian environment on Windows 10/11.

I have this alias already set inside the `.bash_aliases`

```
$ type minikube
minikube is aliased to `"/mnt/c/minikube/minikube.exe"'
```

and I have this script running on WSL2 start up:

```
$ cat wsl_minikube_start.sh
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias_location="${HOME}/.bash_aliases"
source "${alias_location}"
ministart="minikube start"
${ministart}
shopt -u expand_aliases
```

I believe it is supposed to work that way, but it shows the `minikube` command not found.

```
$ bash wsl_minikube_start.sh
wsl_minikube_start.sh: line 5: minikube: command not found
```

(The title was edited to make this easier to find in the future; it was not clear at the time what exactly the problem was.)

Comment: You should not be using aliases in scripts in the first place. You are doing it wrong. The simple fix would be to replace the alias with a function.

Comment: I understand. but it is for my personal laptop and only 2-3 aliases are present inside `.bash_aliases`, so it does not cause harm for this one. Could you point out the fix part of this script?.

Comment: You have not shown your definition of your alias. I suppose that the definition is in .bash_aliases, but you don't show the content of this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting a command in a variable is basically always a bad idea, not only because it interferes with alias expansion (basically, aliases are parsed before variable expansions take place). See e.g. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Aliases are basically always a bad idea, too. Replace your alias with a function instead.

```
minikube () { "/mnt/c/minikube/minikube.exe" "$@"; }
```

Or, basically equivalently, create a wrapper script in your `PATH` with essentially the same contents.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec "/mnt/c/minikube/minikube.exe" "$@"
```

Returning to the first topic, it's not clear why you want to encapsulate the simple command `minikube start` with a variable; but if this really has some purpose, you want to use a function for that, too.

```
ministart () { minikube start "$@"; }
```

(The `"$@"` is only useful if you want to be able to add command-line arguments.)